# How can I make a .delay function in a h3 with JQuery in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selenium

I tried to made a click in an 'h3' that contains two 'divs' so I tried to make a loop to go through them but it only opens the second 'div'.

Just it opens both 'divs' when I put an alert which stop the application between both of them. It works but I want to make this without have to block the application with the alert because I'm using it with Selenium in a Java project of Eclipse.

I tried to make this with a `.delay()` function but it didn't works. I put here the code that I use for it:

```
$("#proveDiv > div > h3").each(function(i, obj){
      $(obj).delay(60000).fadeIn().click();
})
```

It only opens the second 'div', but I want to the test go through both 'divs' and not only on one of them.

I want to know if there is some function like delay or sleep that do this task but without blocking the application.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you very much!

**EDIT:** I also tried with the function setTimeout but it didn't work also. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

```
$("#proveDiv > div > h3").each( function(i) 
{
    setTimeout(function() 
    { 
       $(this).click()} , 10000)
    }  
)
```

Comment: provide some html please!!

Comment: Do you mean the structure of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are executing this Javascript through Selenium and wants to test it. 
How about selecting and clicking them one by one

```
JavascriptExecutor driver = (JavascriptExecutor) webdriver;
driver.executeScript("$(`proveDiv > div > h3`).eq(0).click();");
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(100); // or Thread.sleep(100);
driver.executeScript("$(`proveDiv > div > h3`).eq(1).click();");
```

Comment: Thank you man! I also proved it before but it works separately and I need to click first in one 'div' and some seconds after in the second one. Have you another idea to do this? Thank you again!

Comment: @Error404 Using `TimeUnit.sleep` or `Thread.sleep` will allow you to wait for sometime before clicking on next div.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm sorry for not answer before, but it really works perfectly. I sign your answer up. Thank you again ;)